# Sort elements on page with selected option without using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sort elements on html page by selecting an option in the select tag using javascript. E.g. when I choose "COST" option, the elements in the article tags sort by cost in the p tag and they are shown in a sorted order. I now how to do that with jQuery, but how can I do that without it?

Article section

```
<article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 01</p>
    <img class="this1" src="images/layer4.png" alt="item">
    <p class="quan">QUANTITY</p>
    <p data-num='1' id="article1" class="number2">0</p>
    <button class="plus" onclick="document.getElementById('article1').innerHTML=increment()">+</button>
    <button class="minu" onclick="document.getElementById('article1').innerHTML=decrement()">-</button>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">4232</span></p>
    <button class="add_item" onclick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=increment()" data-id="01">BUY</button>
</article>
<article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 02</p>
    <img class="this1" src="images/layer4.png" alt="item">
    <p class="quan">QUANTITY</p>
    <p  id="article2" class="number2">0</p>
    <button class="plus" onclick="document.getElementById('article2').innerHTML=increment()">+</button>
    <button class="minu" onclick="document.getElementById('article2').innerHTML=decrement()">-</button>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">4242</span></p>
    <button class="add_item" onclick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=increment()" data-id="02">BUY</button>
</article>
<article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 03</p>
    <img class="this1" src="images/layer4.png" alt="item">
    <p class="quan">QUANTITY</p>
    <p id="article3" class="number2">0</p>
    <button class="plus" onclick="document.getElementById('article3').innerHTML=increment()">+</button>
    <button class="minu" onclick="document.getElementById('article3').innerHTML=decrement()">-</button>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">65</span></p>
    <button class="add_item" onclick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=increment()" data-id="03">BUY</button>
</article>
<article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 04</p>
    <img class="this1" src="images/layer4.png" alt="item">
    <p class="quan">QUANTITY</p>
    <p id="article4" class="number2">0</p>
    <button class="plus" onclick="document.getElementById('article4').innerHTML=increment()">+</button>
    <button class="minu" onclick="document.getElementById('article4').innerHTML=decrement()">-</button>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">213</span></p>
    <button class="add_item" onclick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=increment()" data-id="04">BUY</button>
</article>
<article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 05</p>
    <img class="this1" src="images/layer4.png" alt="item">
    <p class="quan">QUANTITY</p>
    <p id="article5" class="number2">0</p>
    <button class="plus" onclick="document.getElementById('article5').innerHTML=increment()">+</button>
    <button class="minu" onclick="document.getElementById('article5').innerHTML=decrement()">-</button>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">5321</span></p>
    <button class="add_item" onclick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML=increment()" data-id="05">BUY</button>
</article>
```

HTML SELECT

```
<p class="sort21">SORT BY:</p>
        <select id="selectop">
            <option value="1">COST</option>
            <option value="2">NAME</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: How do you do it with jQuery? any by what do you sort? amount?

Comment: There are a lot of examples of that on stackoverflow, so it's not a problem. Yes, by amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you have to insert all articles into a div or any type of element you want.

**Second**, use classes of corresponding elements according to which you want to sort, as the value of select tag options. So according to your example we will use item_title, item_price as the values of select tag options.

Now see the full code, it will sort articles according to selected option, you will surely understand. I have shortened you articles for example.

```js
function sort(sortBy) {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item_box");

  // getElementsByClassName returns object. make it a array to use sort function
  var itemsArr = [];
  for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // consider elements only
      itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
  }

  var sorted = itemsArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.getElementsByClassName(sortBy)[0].innerHTML;
    b = b.getElementsByClassName(sortBy)[0].innerHTML;
    
    //decide whether need number sort or string sort
    if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) 
      return a.localeCompare(b);
    else
      return a-b;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; ++i) {
    document.getElementById("items").appendChild(sorted[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 01</p>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">4232</span></p>
  </article>
  <article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 02</p>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">4242</span></p>
  </article>
  <article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 03</p>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">65</span></p>
  </article>
  <article class="item_box">
    <p class="item_title">WIDGET 04</p>
    <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">213</span></p></button>
  </article>
<article class="item_box">
  <p class="item_title">WIDGET 05</p>
  <p class="amount"><span class="item_price">5321</span></p>
</article>  
</div>

<p class="sort21">SORT BY:</p>
<select id="selectop" onchange="sort(this.value)">
  <option value="item_title">NAME</option>
  <option value="item_price">COST</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html to:

```
<p class="sort-label">SORT BY: <span id="sort-value"> </span></p>
<select id="select-sorting" onchange="changeSorting()">
    <option value="cost">COST</option>
    <option value="name">NAME</option>
</select>
```

And add this to the javascript:

```
function changeSorting() {
    var sortBy = document.getElementById("select-sorting").value;
    document.getElementById("sort-value").innerHTML(sortBy);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me also how can I sort these elements by amount for example using only javascript?